# name of my secondary iCloud email account

Tags: macbook-pro

I have set up an email account on iCloud on our shared macbook but when I send a message it comes up with my wife's name (primary account) and then my email address(secondary).   This is for work and I need my own separate account without her name being attached to it.  Does anyone know how I do this?

Comment: Do you have one user for each of you on your MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change your name when you log in to 'manage my apple ID' and explore the options down the left hand side: https://appleid.apple.com